# Flatten function using reduce and each in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

The flatten function is created using the each and reduce functions:

```
function each(collection, iterator) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)){
      for (var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
        iterator(collection[i],i,collection)
      }
    }else {
      for (var key in collection){
        iterator(collection[key],key,collection)
      }
    }
  };



    function reduce(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
    var initalizing = arguments.length === 2;
    each(collection,function(value){
      accumulator = iterator(accumulator,value);
    });
    return accumulator;
  };
```

I tried to use each to iterate over the nested array,if the `toFlatten` is array, it will push `value` to the `array`. if it is not array, it will push the accumulated `flat` numbers to the array... why it is not working?

```
 function flatten(array){
      return reduce(array,function(flat,toFlatten){
          return each(toFlatten,function(value){
             if(Array.isArray(toFlatten)){
                 return array.push(value);
             }
              });
              return array.push(flat)
          },[]);
      };



flatten([[1,2,3],2,3,[3,4,5],5,6]); //nothing returned 
flatten([[1,2,3],2,3,[3,[4,7],5],5,6]);
```

update the answer:

```
function flatten(array) {
    return reduce(array,function(flat,toFlatten){
       if(Array.isArray(toFlatten)){
           each(toFlatten,function(value){
               flat.push(value);

               });

           }else{

               flat.push(toFlatten)


               }

       return flat;

        },[]);

}
```

Comment: `Array.push` returns the `length` of the new array, that's why.

Comment: so what should I push ?

Comment: Return array not array.push: `array.push(value); return array;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your example little bit changed (see comments) and using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
function flatten(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
        if (Array.isArray(toFlatten)) { 
            // if it is an array, iterate it and push each value to flatted result
            toFlatten.forEach(function (value) {
                if (Array.isArray(toFlatten)) {
                    flat.push(value);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // if it is not an array, just push the value to result
            flat.push(toFlatten);
        }
        return flat; // return new flatted result
    }, []);
};

flatten([[1, 2, 3], 2, 3, [ 3, 4, 5 ], 5, 6]);
// Array [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6 ]
```

But you can make it much shorter by calling apply method on [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [[1, 2, 3], 2, 3, [ 3, 4, 5 ], 5, 6]);
```

you can also use it for deeply nested arrays:

```
var array = [[1, 2, 3], 2, 3, [3, [4, 7], 5], 5, 6];
while(array.some(Array.isArray)) {
    array = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], array);
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: but it doest work out my second call, which is two deep?